# How to perform a calculation conditional on a column value in a R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a panel of stock data and would like to calculate the beta of the stocks. Amongst these stocks I have included the SP500 data, which would of course be the market data that I use to calculate the beta for each stock.

I would like to calculate a weekly beta for each of the stocks using the following formula:

cov[R_{i,d (element of) t}, R_{m,d (element of) t}]/var(R_mt)

Where R = Returns, i = asset, d = day, t = week, m = market(SP500)

```
ave_beta <- df %>%
  group_by(asset, week) %>%
  summarize(ave_beta = ??? ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This is my code so far, however, I am not sure how to filter my data to include the SP500 data.

As I effectively want a weekly beta calculated from daily data for each asset.

EDIT:

Example of my data below:

```
        date open high  low close   volume asset week lclose          ret logclose
2 2020-06-29 4.36 4.41 4.31  4.35 30270600   NOK    1   4.34  0.002301497 1.470176
3 2020-06-30 4.30 4.41 4.30  4.40 21440300   NOK    1   4.35  0.011428696 1.481605
4 2020-07-01 4.36 4.41 4.34  4.35 24700300   NOK    1   4.40 -0.011428696 1.470176
5 2020-07-02 4.43 4.50 4.43  4.44 26398700   NOK    1   4.35  0.020478531 1.490654
6 2020-07-06 4.63 4.75 4.59  4.60 56364200   NOK    2   4.44  0.035401927 1.526056
7 2020-07-07 4.57 4.58 4.30  4.31 58948300   NOK    2   4.60 -0.065118399 1.460938
```

```
        date     open     high      low  close   volume asset week lclose           ret logclose
7890 2021-06-18 201.3928 204.8400 194.5100 199.19  6663813  MRNA   51 202.47 -0.0163325843 5.294259
7891 2021-06-21 200.8600 211.0400 200.0000 208.24  7423063  MRNA   52 199.19  0.0444321176 5.338691
7892 2021-06-22 210.7600 222.4048 210.2501 221.36 10066344  MRNA   52 208.24  0.0610990748 5.399790
7893 2021-06-23 219.9800 224.5700 205.5500 212.04 14558440  MRNA   52 221.36 -0.0430153994 5.356775
7894 2021-06-24 214.3800 221.4900 213.4600 220.14  8171884  MRNA   52 212.04  0.0374887715 5.394264
7895 2021-06-25 221.2600 226.5100 216.3300 219.94 13315616  MRNA   52 220.14 -0.0009089257 5.393355
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your `df`? It's easier to help you knowing how you data looks like.

Comment: @patL Edited now to include the head and tail of the df, thank you

Comment: please use `dput` on a subset of your `df` data instead of copy-pasting screen output, which is tedious to get into shape for R.